# Use azure-notificationhubs-java-backend via proxy with authentication

Tags: java, azure-notificationhub

Is there a way to use the azure-notificationhubs-java-backend library behind a corporate proxy with authentication?

I will be using the library under an application server (JBoss 6), so I'd like to avoid the classic Java system properties approach (https.proxyHost, https.proxyPort, etc.), since it affects the whole JVM.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Nuno Guerreiro

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem. I'm posting the solution here, just in case anyone needs it ;).

In my specific case, I use a Windows 8 PC and my proxy requires Windows (NTLM) authentication. The code below uses NTLM integrated authentication, i.e., no username and password need to be explicitly set, since the security credentials of the currently logged-on user will be used.

```
import com.windowsazure.messaging.*;

import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.config.AuthSchemes;
import org.apache.http.concurrent.FutureCallback;
import org.apache.http.config.Registry;
import org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicSchemeFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.DigestSchemeFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.win.WindowsCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.win.WindowsNTLMSchemeFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.win.WindowsNegotiateSchemeFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.WinHttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder;

public class Test9 {
    private static HttpAsyncClientBuilder createAsyncBuilderWithProxy(String proxyHost, int proxyPort) {
        if (WinHttpClients.isWinAuthAvailable()) {
            final Registry<AuthSchemeProvider> authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeProvider>create()
                    .register(AuthSchemes.BASIC, new BasicSchemeFactory())
                    .register(AuthSchemes.DIGEST, new DigestSchemeFactory())
                    .register(AuthSchemes.NTLM, new WindowsNTLMSchemeFactory(null))
                    .register(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, new WindowsNegotiateSchemeFactory(null))
                    .build();
            final CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new WindowsCredentialsProvider(new SystemDefaultCredentialsProvider());
            return HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create()
                    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                    .setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry)
                    .setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort));
        } else {
            return HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create().setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if(args.length < 4) {
            System.err.println("syntax: java Test9 <hub connection string> <hub name> <push notification address> <push message>");
        } else {
            String hubConnectionString = args[0];
            String hubName = args[1];
            String pushNotificationAddress = args[2];
            String pushMessage = args[3];

            CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient = createAsyncBuilderWithProxy("proxy.corporate.com", 8080).build();
            httpClient.start();
            HttpClientManager.setHttpAsyncClient(httpClient);

            NotificationHub hub = new NotificationHub(hubConnectionString, hubName);

            Notification notification = Notification.createGcmNotifiation(pushMessage);

            hub.sendDirectNotification(notification, pushNotificationAddress);

            System.out.println("Notification sent!");

            httpClient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `azure-notificationhubs-java-backend` library without the proxy setting apis, there seems to be not any way to use it via proxy with authentication without any affection for the whole JVM of your JBoss.

So per my experience, the only way is creating a new instance of JBoss server using Java system properties for proxy settings to run your Azure notificationhubs java backend and communicate with your main application on the other JBoss server instance via the RPC ways like REST API, WS* API, etc.

Hope it helps.